# <method> was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, signature

I'm trying to overload operator<< in C++ to use a recursive private method to get the content of a binary search tree as a string. I keep getting the "not declared in this scope" error despite checking the method signature for inconsistencies. I don't understand why the call to recursiveOutput() in operator<< causes this error.

operator<< definition:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const BinTree&);
```

recursive method definition:

```
void recursiveOutput(Node*, string&);
```

operator<< implementation:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const BinTree& rhs)
{
    string result;
    recursiveOutput(rhs.root, result);
    os << result;
    return os;
}
```

The BinTree class has the private member "root" which is a pointer to the structure "Node".

EDIT: Example code

```
class BinTree
{
    public:
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const BinTree&);
    private:
        struct Node
        {
            string data;
            Node* left;
            Node* right;
        };

        Node* root;

        void recursiveOutput(Node*, string&);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const BinTree& rhs)
{
    string result;
    rhs.recursiveOutput(rhs.root, result);
    os << result;
    return os;
}

void BinTree::recursiveOutput(Node* currentRoot, string& result)
{
    // if currentRoot is NULL return
    if (currentRoot == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    // traverse left branch
    recursiveOutput(currentRoot->left, result);
    // append string from NodeData
    std::ostringstream stream;
    stream << *currentRoot->data;
    result.append(stream.str());
    result.append(" ");
    // traverse right branch
    recursiveOutput(currentRoot->right, result);
}
```

EDIT: The reason this causes an error is because operator<< is not a member of BinTree, so it cannot call a member function without a BinTree object to call it.

Comment: Show the definition of `BinTree`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Is `recursiveOutput` a member function or free function?  If it's a member, you need to call it as one.

Comment: could it be that recursiveOutput() is a member function of BinTree? In that case, you should rhs.recursiveOutput(...)

Comment: Does getting rid of the `const` in `operator<<(..., const BinTree&)`, change anything? Or, alternatively, changing `recursiveOutput()` to accept a `const Node*`?

Comment: The problem was that I could not call recursiveOutput() within operator<< without a calling object. Changing the line to `rhs.recursiveOutput(rhs.roo, result);` worked.